# How do you pass cookies with Apollo Federation?

Tags: typescript, api, cookies, graphql, apollo

If a user successfully logs in, and I send a cookie to the client... how would I send that cookie through the gateway and how would I parse that cookie to send to my subgraphs for authorization? Any help or a direction to go in would be super helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, using NestJS. Here's my code solution.

```
// graphql-data-source.ts
import { GraphQLDataSourceProcessOptions, RemoteGraphQLDataSource } from "@apollo/gateway";
import { GraphQLDataSourceRequestKind } from "@apollo/gateway/dist/datasources/types";

export class GraphQLDataSource extends RemoteGraphQLDataSource {
  didReceiveResponse({ response, context }): typeof response {
    const cookies = response.http.headers?.raw()["set-cookie"] as string[] | null;

    if (cookies) {
      context?.req.res.append("set-cookie", cookies);
    }

    return response;
  }

  willSendRequest(params: GraphQLDataSourceProcessOptions) {
    const { request, kind } = params;

    if (kind === GraphQLDataSourceRequestKind.INCOMING_OPERATION) {
      const cookie = params?.incomingRequestContext.request.http.headers.get("Cookie");
      request.http.headers.set("Cookie", cookie);
    }
  }
}
```

`willSendRequest` - is responsible of passing the cookie in communication from client to server.
`didReceiveResponse` - is responsible of passing the cookie in communication from server to client.

Update your app module.

```
// app.module.ts

GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloGatewayDriverConfig>({
  driver: ApolloGatewayDriver,
  gateway: {
    buildService: (args) => new GraphQLDataSource(args),
    supergraphSdl: new IntrospectAndCompose({
      subgraphs: [
        //...
      ],
    }),
  },
});
```

I have also imported "cookie-parser" in main.ts, but I think it might be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

What framework do you use?

I had the same problem while implementing authorization in NestJS. Answers from [this issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/3099) helped me a lot. Especially the last one (I think you can easily adapt this solution for any other framework):

```
didReceiveResponse({ response, context }) {
    const cookies = response.http.headers?.raw()['set-cookie'] as string[] | null;

    if (cookies) {
      context?.req.res.append('set-cookie', cookies);
    }

    return response;
}
```